# Why are pressure-stabilized rockets not more common?

Tags: technology, mass-fraction

The Atlas rockets and Centaur upper stages (often used in combination) successfully use(d) pressure-stabilized tanks to minimize dry mass. This technology was not used in any other rocket stages I'm familiar with. Given the high value of a pound of payload, why?

Comment: I presume you read [Taming Liquid Hydrogen: The Centaur Upper Stage Rocket, 1958-2002](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=20040084080)? (Warning: large PDF file on NTRS - expect a server struggling to keep connection alive and download with a download manager with resume capability!) For those not familiar with the term _pressure-stabilized tank_,  the question is about sub-millimeter thin _balloon tanks_ much lighter than reinforced structure tanks.

Answer (score 5):

The high price of payload to orbit is precisely the point: Pressure stabilization means that the entire transport of the tanks has to be done with the greatest care. Any dropped tool can easily punch a hole through the paper-thin tank walls. They also have to be constantly wetted with an oil film to prevent corrosion.

The additional labour adds greatly to the cost of the launch system.